# For loop Vba with 2 variable

Tags: vba, loops

arrayOne(1) = A arrayTwo(1) = B 
arrayOne(2) = C arrayTwo(2) = D 
arrayOne(3) = E arrayTwo(3) = F

I need to loop through two arrays to call a sub. Note the sub is always called in pair, e.g.:

Sub(arrayOne(1), arrayTwo(1)) 
Sub(arrayOne(2), arrayTwo(2))

Is it possible  to initialize a for with two variables? Something like that:

```
For x = LBound(arrayOne) To UBound(arrayOne) and y = LBound(arrayTwo) To UBound(arrayTwo)

   Call Sub(x, y) 

Next x
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `For Next` loop cannot use two indexers
If you sure that arrays are same size, then you can use same indexer for both arrays

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(arrayOne) To UBound(arrayOne)
    Call Sub(arrayOne(i), arrayTwo(i)) 
Next i
```

Comment: Simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

Why not hierarchical?

```
For x = LBound(arrayOne) To UBound(arrayOne)
    For y = LBound(arrayTwo) To UBound(arrayTwo)
        Call Sub(x, y) 
    Next y
Next x
```